# Printing the values of specific data types in C?

Tags: c

I'm trying to print out three columns:

Value:   Datatype:   Size(in bytes):

to the console:

```
#include <stdio.h>
/*
print out the primitive (basic built in) data types for C
along with their size in bytes.
*/
int main(){
    char letter = 'j';
    short int x = 55437;
    long int y = 1234567;
    double dbl = 5.99;
    float boobs = 4.66;

    printf("Value:    Datatype:  Size(in bytes):\n\n");

    printf("%c\t  char\t   %c\n", letter, sizeof(letter));
    printf("%d\t  short\t   %d\n", x, sizeof(x));
    printf("%ld\t  long\t   %ld\n", y, sizeof(y));
    printf("%lf\t  double\t   %lf\n", dbl, sizeof(dbl));
    printf("%f\t  float\t   %f\n", boobs, sizeof(boobs));
}
```

I almost got it, but I'm still having some incorrect output: 
[image: new problems]

Why is my short int printing out as -10099 (contradicting that I had already assigned it to 55437)? And why are my double and float data type specifiers in the Datatype column being shifted so far right?

Comment: You're not using the appropriate format specifier for the other variable types. `%c` is just for characters.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I got it to look right :) How do I mark my question solved?

Comment: Click the checkmark next to the answer which you think is the best (or helped you the most).

Comment: the right shifting is due to a \t is 8 char, with the first tab being in column 7 and each successive tab being 8 columns to the right.  so when a value overlays the first tab position, then outputing a tab will jump to the second tab position.

Comment: The maximum value a **short** can store is 32767 , any larger and it 'rolls around ' like a car odometer; except worse, it becomes large and negative, before eventually returning to 0 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
printf("%c\tchar\t   %d\n", letter, (int)sizeof(letter));
printf("%hd\tshort\t   %d\n", x, (int)sizeof(x));//55437 > max of int16
printf("%ld\tlong\t   %d\n", y, (int)sizeof(y));
printf("%f\tdouble\t   %d\n", mile, (int)sizeof(mile));
printf("%f\tfloat\t   %d\n", wage, (int)sizeof(wage));
```

Comment: Do you know offhand what the maximum value for int16 is in C? Maybe if I switch to a number less than that, it will fix my -10099 problem.

Comment: @SamPeterson because the short in your environment is 2 bytes, 55437 exceed the upper limit that can be its representation. `short`(2 byte integer) : -32768～32767

Answer (score 1):

When a value is printed with `"%c"` in `printf`, it's converted to `unsigned char`. However, for ASCII, only values ranging from `0x20` to `0x7E` are [printable characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_printable_characters). How the other characters are shown is up to the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

try this :)

```
printf("%c\t  char\t   %g\n", letter, sizeof(letter));
printf("%d\t  short\t   %g\n", x, sizeof(x));
printf("%ld\t  long\t   %g\n", y, sizeof(y));
printf("%g.2\t  double\t   %g\n", dbl, sizeof(dbl));
printf("%f.2\t  float\t   %g\n", boobs, sizeof(boobs));
```

Comment: you forgot to attach the (datatype) to the left hand side of sizeof.